# Show $P(A \subset B) = (\frac{3}{4})^n$

Tags: probability-theory, elementary-set-theory

> ​Let $S = \{1, 2, \dots, n \}$ and​​ suppose that $A$ and $B$ are,
>   independently, equally likely to be any of the $2^n$ subsets of $S$.
>
> Show that $P(A \subset B) = (\frac{3}{4})^n$ and show that $P(A \cap B = \emptyset) = (\frac{3}{4})^n$.

Applying the law of total probability ,

$$P(A \subset B)  =\sum_{k=0}^n P(A \subset B \Large \mid \normalsize |B| = k)P(|B| = k) $$

If $k = 0$ then $B = \varnothing $. Therefore  $P(A \subset B \Large \mid \normalsize |B| = k) = 0$ because there **do not exist** any sets $A$ such that $A \subset B$.

If $k = 1$ and $A \subset B$, then there exists precisely one set $A$ such that $A \subset B$, and this $A = \varnothing$. Therefore

$$\begin{align}
&P(A \subset B \mid \normalsize |B| = k) =  \frac{1}{2^n} = \frac{2^1 - 1}{2^n} = \frac{2^k - 1}{2^n} \\ 
&P(|B| = k) = \frac{\binom{n}{k}}{2^n}
\end{align}$$

If  $A \subset B$, then $A \in  \mathcal{P}(B) - B$. Thus, there are $|\mathcal{P}(B) - B| = 2^{k} - 1$ possibilities for $A \subset B$ out of a possible $2^{|S|} = 2^n$ sample space.

Therefore I have

$$\begin{align}
&P(A \subset B)  = 0 + \sum_{k=1}^n P(A \subset B \Large \mid \normalsize |B| = k)P(|B| = k) = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2^k - 1}{2^n}\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{2^n}  \\
&\mathsf{but} \ \ \  \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{2^k - 1}{2^n}\frac{\binom{n}{k}}{2^n} \ne (\frac{3}{4})^n
\end{align}$$

Where is my mistake? **Hints only** please.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is easy to see that $P(A\subseteq B)=(\frac34)^n$ so the first part of what you're trying to show can't be true.

Namely, suppose we choose for each of the $n$ possible elements first whether it is in $A$ and then whether it is in $B$. All of the $2n$ choices are independent and uniformly distributed between yes and no.

$A\subseteq B$ means that each *pair* of answers is one of (yes, yes), (no, yes) or (no, no). For each pair the probability of that happening is $\frac 34$, so the probabilty of that happening for all $n$ pairs is $(\frac{3}{4})^n$.

Similarly $A\cap B=\varnothing$ means that each pair of answers is one of (yes,no), (no, yes), or (no,no). Again, this has probability $\frac 34$ and must happen $n$ times, so the probability of disjoint $A$ and $B$ is $(\frac 34)^n$.

---

Trying to count possibilities, grouped by the size of the sets is definitely the long way around to an answer here.

Comment: Specifically, I mean $A \subset B$ and not $A \subseteq B$. Sorry but this is not so easy for me to see. (Why should this be easy or obvious?)

Comment: @mathMajor: Paragraph 2 and 3 of the answer explain why $P(A\subseteq B)=(\frac34)^n$. Since $A\subseteq B$ contains strictly more cases than $A\subsetneq B$ does, $(\frac34)^n$ can't also be the probability of the smaller event.

Comment: Your answer makes sense and is shorter than solving this with conditional probability. It's just that the textbook specifically says to solve it this way. So my question remains: where have I made a mistake?

Comment: @mathMajor: Are you sure you have made a mistake? Since the probability you're trying to compute is not in fact $(\frac34)^n$, getting a different answer from that does not necessarily indicate a mistake.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to calculate strictly about the case of $A\subset B$, from my persepective there is nothing wrong about your calculation. But if you want to consider about the case of $A\subseteq B$， the above answer is direct and simple. I  would like to give a solution using the law of total probability.

$$
P(A \subseteq B)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} P(A\subseteq B \mid |B|=i)\cdot P(|B|=i)=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n} \frac{2^i}{2^n} \cdot \frac{\left(\begin{array}{c}
n\\i\end{array}\right)}{2^n}=\frac{\sum\limits_{i=0}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}
n\\i\end{array}\right)2^i1^{n-i}}{4^n}=\frac{3^n}{4^n}
$$
The second question is similar.